# pyqgis plugin error list has not attributes

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

hello I create a QGIS plugin using pyqgis and I have two buttons in my plugin window button 1(run `perform_search(self)` function) and button 2(run `select_feature(self)` function).

to work button 2 function must be first running function from button 1 because that function from button 2 need found list where create that list in function from button 1.

but if I run button 2 I take error ins found list :

`found  has not attributes`

any idea why ?

button 1 :

```
def perform_search(self):
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("layer")[0]
    ...................................
    self.found = []
    self.results.clear()
    layername='mmm'
    for feature in layer.getFeatures(request):
        abc=feature.attribute("my_name")
        self.found.append([layername,feature.attribute("my_name")])
        self.results.addItem(abc)
```

button 2 :

```
def select_feature(self):
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("layer")[0]
    # Deselect
    for layer, feature in self.found:
        layer.removeSelection()

    # To find extent of selected items
    centroids = []
    transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(layer.crs(), self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().destinationCrs())
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: in the 2. line in button 2 you define the variable layer, later one you define layer as an iterator over your list. change one of the variables to something else and check if this solves your problem